# How to find the general solution of $\sin \left(\theta +\frac{\pi }{6}\right) =\cos 3\theta $

Tags: trigonometry

Find the ***general solution*** of the equation.

> \begin{eqnarray} \sin \left(\theta +\frac{\pi }{6}\right)\space
>  =\space \cos 3\theta \\ \end{eqnarray}

The answers in my book are $\left(6n+1\right)\frac{\pi }{12},\space \left(n-\frac{1}{6}\right)\pi $.

Should I first convert all the things to cos(xxx)=??? or sin(xxx)=???.

So I try :

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \sin \theta \cos \frac{\pi }{6}+\cos \theta \sin \frac{\pi }{6}&=&\cos 2\theta \cos \theta -\sin 2\theta \sin \theta \\
> \sin \theta \cos \frac{\pi }{6}+\sin 2\theta \sin \theta &=&\cos 2\theta \cos \theta -\cos \theta \sin \frac{\pi }{6}\\
> \sin \theta \left(\sin 2\theta +\cos \frac{\pi }{6}\right)&=&\cos \theta \left(\cos 2\theta -\sin \frac{\pi }{6}\right)\\
> \\?...&=&...?\\
> \end{eqnarray}

What should I do?

I do not know whether my direction is correct.

***Thank you for your attention.***

Update 1 :
[image]

I can get the first ans by using method 1 but I cannot find the next one$\space \left(n-\frac{1}{6}\right)\pi $.

Comment: You can use Euler's formulas to prove nearly any trig identity you can think of : $sin(x) = (e^{ix} - e^{-ix})/(2i)$ and $cos(x) = (e^{ix} + e^{-ix})/2$.  It might be a bit beyond the curriculum of trig, but it's easy and might let you get a correct answer on a test ^_^

Comment: ...sorry posted this response on the wrong question...

Comment: No problem^^, I need more tries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method** $1:$

As $\cos(\frac\pi2-x)=\sin x$

$$\cos3\theta=\sin\left(\theta+\frac\pi6\right)=\cos\{\frac\pi2-\left(\theta+\frac\pi6\right)\}$$

$$\cos3\theta=\cos \left(\frac\pi3-\theta\right)$$

Now, we know $\cos x=\cos A\implies x=2n\pi\pm A$ where $n$ is any integer

**Method** $2:$

As $\sin(\frac\pi2-x)=\cos x$

$$\sin\left(\theta+\frac\pi6\right)=\cos3\theta=\sin\left(\frac\pi2-3\theta\right)$$

Now, we know $\sin x=\sin B\implies x=m\pi+(-1)^m B$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: Do you mean cos3θ=sin(π/2−3θ)?Thank.

Comment: @CasperLi, thanks for your observation. Rectified the typo